# How do I insert my Python dictionary into my SQL Server database table?

Tags: python, sql-server, pandas, dictionary

I have a dictionary with 3 keys which correspond to field names in a SQL Server table. The values of these keys come from an excel file and I store this dictionary in a dataframe which I now need to insert into a SQL table. This can all be seen in the code below:

```
import pandas as pd
import pymssql
df=[]
fp = "file path" 
data = pd.read_excel(fp,sheetname ="CRM View" )
row_date = data.loc[3, ]
row_sita = "ABZPD"
row_event = data.iloc[12, :]        
df = pd.DataFrame({'date': row_date,
                           'sita': row_sita,
                           'event': row_event
                           }, index=None)
df = df[4:]
df = df.fillna("")
print(df)
```

My question is how do I insert this dictionary into a SQL table now?

Also, as a side note, this code is part of a loop which needs to go through several excel files one by one, insert the data into dictionary then into SQL then delete the data in the dictionary and start again with the next excel file.

Comment: pandas provides a [to_sql](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html) method. ```df.to_sql()```

Comment: Not familar with Python but to pass a table structure like that to a SQL Stored Procedure (if you are using that) you can use a table type and pass that with data into your SP and insert from that.  I did similar with Dictionary object in C# and populated it and passed that to the SP in SQL call

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
import MySQLdb
# connect
conn = MySQLdb.connect("127.0.0.1","username","passwore","table")
x = conn.cursor()

# write
x.execute('INSERT into table (row_date, sita, event) values ("%d", "%d", "%d")' % (row_date, sita, event))

# close
conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

You might have to change it a little based on your SQL restrictions, but should give you a good start anyway.

Answer (score 0):

For the pandas dataframe, you can use the pandas built-in method [to_sql](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html) to store in db. Following is the way to use it.

```
import sqlalchemy as sa
params = urllib.quote_plus("DRIVER={};SERVER={};DATABASE={};Trusted_Connection=True;".format("{SQL Server}",
                                                                              "<db_server_url>",
                                                                              "<db_name>"))


conn_str = 'mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect={}'.format(params)
engine = sa.create_engine(conn_str)
df.to_sql(<table_name>, engine,schema=<schema_name>, if_exists="append", index=False)
```

For this method you you will need to install `sqlalchemy` package.

`pip install sqlalchemy`

You will also need to setup the MSSql DSN on the machine.